# How to get the row/column labels of a Confusion Matrix from scikit-learn?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

How would I confirm the the columns/rows of an outputted Confusion Matrix if I didn't initially specify them when creating the matrix such as in the below code:

```
    y_true = ["cat", "ant", "cat", "cat", "ant", "bird"]
    y_pred = ["ant", "ant", "cat", "cat", "ant", "cat"]
    cm=confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)

    array([[2, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 1],
           [1, 0, 2]])
```

From the docs I know it says `If none is given, those that appear at least once in y_true or y_pred are used in sorted order` so I would assume the columns/rows would be `("ant", "bird", "cat")` but how do I confirm that? 
I tried something like `cm.labels` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In the [source code of the confusion_matrix](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dba/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L257):

```
if labels is None:
    labels = unique_labels(y_true, y_pred)
```

What is `unique_labels` and where is it imported from?

```
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import unique_labels
unique_labels(y_true, y_pred)
```

Returns

```
array(['ant', 'bird', 'cat'],
      dtype='<U4')
```

`unique_labels` [extracts an ordered array](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dbac82d362f296dc2746f10e43ffa1615660/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py#L42) of unique labels.

Examples:

```
>>> from sklearn.utils.multiclass import unique_labels
>>> unique_labels([3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7])
array([3, 5, 7])
>>> unique_labels([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 3, 4])
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> unique_labels([1, 2, 10], [5, 11])
array([ 1,  2,  5, 10, 11])
```

Maybe a more intuitive example:

```
unique_labels(['z', 'x', 'y'], ['a', 'z', 'c'], ['e', 'd', 'y'])
```

Returns:

```
array(['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
      dtype='<U1')
```